# About "tadashii", present or past

Tags: て-form, tense

It's the literal translation of this line

> お前を**正しい**と受け入れていた俺の心が弱かった
>   omae o **tadashii** to ukeireteita ore no kokoro ga yowakatta

"My heart was weak because accept that you are right" or "My heart was weak because accepted that you were right?" I understand that "tadashii" word it's in present form, past form it's "tadashii katta", right? Or there are any way to that word can be in past form in this line without change it?

It's the line in 28:59 to 29:04 in this video. youtube.com/watch?v=8o01LRQx7wM&t=366s Don't look the subtitules please.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35929/7810

Comment: @broccoliforest is it a quoting とhere? it feels different to me.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky exactly my thought, also using an I-adjective as a "verb" like "to be right" feels so weird for me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japanese is just like algebra:
The past tense (present tense A + present tense B)= past tense A + past tense B

I'll show you an example:
当時｛とうじ｝、お前｛まえ｝が好｛す｝きだと俺｛おれ｝は思｛おも｝っていた。
I thought I loved you in those days.

> Is the 正しい a present form
>   in "お前を正しいと受け入れていた俺の心が弱かった"?
>   Is the 好きだ a present form in "当時｛とうじ｝、お前｛まえ｝が好｛す｝きだと俺｛おれ｝は思｛おも｝っていた"?

Yes, 正しい and 好きだ are both expressed in a present form.
I'll show you why.
We Japanese think "お前が正しい" is the present state at the time when 俺の心 accepted the state, because the state is judged not **by the absolute time axis but by the relative axis in Japanese**.
In other words, you have to ride on a time machine in Japan to interpret Japanese.

Comment: Then "tadashii" in this case it's in past form? There it's no need of "tadashii katta" in this line"?

Comment: Anyone can answer to this please?

Comment: It's the line in 28:59 to 29:04 in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8o01LRQx7wM&t=366s Don't look the subtitules please.

Comment: So interesting how different languages handle logic, time, etc

Comment: Thank you very much, then even if 正しい it's in present form, in that line the meaning it's still in past form, right? Because 俺の心 accepted the state in the past. So "My heart was weak because accepted that you were right?" it's the correct translation, all in past form. Right?

Comment: @Shirou How about thinking the sentence like: 俺の心 accepted and said "お前 is right".

Comment: Personally i rather the other translation if it's right, thanks! Also it can be that 正しい not have "katta" to avoid the excesive use of "katta" in the line, right?

Comment: @Shirou >"katta" to avoid the excesive use of "katta" in the line, right? Hmm... Right! In spite of algebra in Japan, お前が**正しかった**と俺は受け入れた and お前が**正しい**と俺は受け入れた have the same meaning as: I accepted that you were right.
If I hear both phrases, the former one has a nuance I'm imaging the scene of the past from here, on the other hand, as for the latter one, I'm standing in the past time and imaging the scene there.